# Should 'Looks Ok' in Triage auto-upvote, or at least generate a prompt to?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, triage, upvotes

In the Triage review queue, when you decide a question 'Looks Ok', and two others have already, it prompts you to upvote the question. However what about the two others who thought it was a good question? Maybe they should have a notification:

[image]

Although maybe this is going a bit far? What about an option when you click 'Looks Ok', since upvotes aren't normally after reaching a consensus with others:

[image]

But that would slow using the queue down quite a lot. We could have an extra button:

[image]

Which raises the question of a downvote for 'Unsalvagable'. Or maybe 'Looks Ok' (and possibly 'Unsalvagable') would automatically upvote/downvote, but we should probably add text somewhere stating that it would happen.

If any of this happens, another question is whether or not it should be subject to the daily limit of 40.

Comment: Just because I think something *"Looks OK"* doesn't mean I think it deserves an upvote so definetely not automatic.

Comment: There are already too many "looks-ok" review bots. What would we do when one of these users gets review banned because it turns out they weren't really paying attention when reviewing? Invalidate all their previous auto-votes?

Comment: @yivi That's definitely something that creates a problem.

Comment: @yivi But if we use the extra button option, we just have to hope they don't use 'Good', and instead use 'Looks Ok'. Thanks to badges like 'Vox Populi', 'Suffarage', 'Civic Duty' etc., I think we may already have spam voting.

Answer (score 10):

"looks OK" is far from "this question shows research effort; it is useful and clear" or "this answer is useful".

"looks OK" is "this doesn't need editing or deserve a down/close vote or a flag"

So there definitely shouldn't be an automatic up-vote and probably shouldn't be a prompt.

Comment: So what about the extra button option I proposed - its use could mean 'this question shows research effort; it is useful and clear' (though that probably shouldn't go on the button itself).

Comment: The triage queue does suggest to upvote an answer if the consensus is "Looks OK"

Comment: @Braiam See the first paragraph of my question, and the second.